# C# Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am trying to create an entity for a SQL Server view.

I am trying to add the `[ToTable]` from my entity class as I am going to include it as a `DbSet`.

I'm using `[ToTable]` and getting an error message type and namespace for ToTable not found.

What would be the namespace for `[ToTable]` while adding to the class?

Comment: Please add some more details and show what you have tried so far.

Comment: [ToTable] sounds familiar to me but not sure where it is, so where did you find/know about it?

Answer (score 2):

ToTable() is the fluent api version (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591617.aspx#2). For annotations you want

```
[Table("databaseName"]
public class ClassName...
```

From System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema; https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg193958.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396